# Error in Centroid calculation of kmeans in matlab

Tags: matlab, k-means

I got a strange output of kMeans implemented in matlab.
All my entries in my input matrix **F** of dimension d x n are between 0 and 1. When i run the kmeans algorithm using the following matlab command which creates 50 cluster.

```
[IDX, B] = kmeans(F,50,'MaxIter',1000,'EmptyAction','singleton')
```

Here IDX is the label returned and B is the centroid of cluster created. Since all your data points are in [0,1]^d , you expect the calculated centroid is also in [0,1]^d , where d is the dimension of the point.

However, the resultant centroid which i got from kmeans after several different initialization contains **negative** value.

Can anyone let me know the reason for it?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the negative values with `F=rand(1000,5);`. Give us code to reproduce it.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? Could you answer the questions?

Answer (score 1):

I can't really answer your question without the actual data matrix "F". However, I note that, if size(F) == [d, n] then the code

```
[IDX, B] = kmeans(F,50,'MaxIter',1000,'EmptyAction','singleton')
```

will treat F as a set of d points, each of n-variables. So all d points belong to [0,1]^n.

Also

1. Do you really need the optional arguments? What happens if you remove them?
2. What happens if you reduce the the number of data points in the input matrix F?
3. what happens if you reduce the the number of clusters, to say 10, instead of 50?